# PHP/AJAX/Mysql generated table links not working correctly

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I have several tables on our site that are generated via pulling data from a mysql database.  I have hyper links in the table that the user needs to be able to click on.  When clicked, specific corresponding cell data needs to be recognized and returned.  I have partially accomplished this with a for loop of each row;HOWEVER, the consequences of this is that the user needs to click the link twice to get it to work AND since the rows are "activated" if they click on another row, the AJAX command is triggered for that row as well.  Which requires inefficient work arounds to avoid problems.  For example, if the row/record contains a "delete record" link attached to AJAX => PHP command, it will delete any row on the table if it's clicked even without clicking the link.

Table is rendered with a PHP query from Mysql with links in on each row to correspond to each row.

```
$mainid=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST["mcnum"]);
$useid=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST["dlnum"]);

$sql="SELECT id,subname AS name,description AS des,pct,
score
FROM probability LEFT JOIN a_score ON a_score.subid=probability.id
WHERE probability.maincat='$maincatid' AND a_score.oppid='$dealid'";
$result=mysqli_query($connect,$sql);

echo '
<div style="height:160px;overflow:scroll;" id="subpad">
<table style="font-size:12px;" id="strtlist">
<tr>
<th style="border: 1px solid black;position:sticky;top:0;background-color:#A9D0F5;">Save Changes</th>
<th style="border: 1px solid black;position:sticky;top:0;background-color:#A9D0F5;">ID</th>
<th style="border: 1px solid black;position:sticky;top:0;background-color:#A9D0F5;">NAME</th>
<th style="border: 1px solid black;position:sticky;top:0;background-color:#A9D0F5;">Description</th>
<th style="border: 1px solid black;position:sticky;top:0;background-color:#A9D0F5;">Target %</th>
<th style="border: 1px solid black;position:sticky;top:0;background-color:#A9D0F5;">Your Score</th>
</tr>';

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

    echo "<tr style='background-color:#FFFFFF;'>
    <td style='border: 1px solid black;'><a href='' id='savelnk' name='nmsvlnk' class='linksc'>Save</a><a href='' id='savelnk2'                                 name='nmsvlnk2' class='linksc2' style='color:blue;'>Erase</a></td>

    <td style='border: 1px solid black;'>".$row['id']."</td>
    <td style='border: 1px solid black;'>".$row['name']."</td>
    <td style='border: 1px solid black;'>".$row['des']."</td>
    <td style='border: 1px solid black;'>".$row['pct']."%</td>
    <td style='border: 1px solid black;' contenteditable>".$row['score']."%</td>
    </tr>";

}

echo '</table>';
echo '</div>';
```

********THIS IS THE FOR LOOP FUNCTION I'm USING*************

```
$(document).on('click', '#savelnk', function() {
  event.preventDefault();

  for (var i = 0; i < strtlist.length; i++) {
    strtlist.rows[i].onclick = function() {
      rIndex = this.rowIndex;
      var recordid = this.cells[1].innerHTML;
      var nwscore = this.cells[5].innerHTML;
      $.post('includes/updatescore.php', {
        recordid: recordid,
        nwscore: nwscore
      }, function(data) {
        alert(data);
      });
    };
  }
});
```

Comment: Why are you using `onclick` if you're using jQuery?

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: The [object-oriented interface to `mysqli`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php) is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface where missing a single `i` can cause trouble. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era and should not be used in new code.

Answer (score 0):

You should not add a click handler inside a click handler. Just do what you want in the main click handler.

Another problem is that you're repeating `id="savelink"` in every row. IDs must be unique, you should use a class instead.

So the PHP should be:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

    echo "<tr style='background-color:#FFFFFF;'>
    <td style='border: 1px solid black;'><a href='' name='nmsvlnk' class='linksc savelnk'>Save</a><a href='' id='savelnk2'                                 name='nmsvlnk2' class='linksc2' style='color:blue;'>Erase</a></td>

    <td style='border: 1px solid black;'>".$row['id']."</td>
    <td style='border: 1px solid black;'>".$row['name']."</td>
    <td style='border: 1px solid black;'>".$row['des']."</td>
    <td style='border: 1px solid black;'>".$row['pct']."%</td>
    <td style='border: 1px solid black;' contenteditable>".$row['score']."%</td>
    </tr>";

}
```

and the JS should be

```
$("#strtlist").on('click', '.savelnk', function() {
  event.preventDefault();

  var recordid = this.cells[1].innerHTML;
  var nwscore = this.cells[5].innerHTML;
  $.post('includes/updatescore.php', {
    recordid: recordid,
    nwscore: nwscore
  }, function(data) {
    alert(data);
  });
});
```